# Java TLS connection behaviour

Tags: java, wireshark, ssl

I use a java TLS server with custom KeyManager, TrustManager and with client authentication. The connection works and certificates are exchanged, also the client (firefox) says that the connection is encrypted. I analyze the connection with wireshark but i don't see tls messages, wireshark shows only tcp segments without decoding the payload (such as TLS client hello, server hello, etc).
I enable the debug logging an this is the log of the server:

> ```
> trigger seeding of SecureRandom
> done seeding SecureRandom
> Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
> Allow legacy hello messages: true
> Is initial handshake: true
> Is secure renegotiation: false
> Thread-1, called closeSocket()
> ```

Comment: There is no question here, but Wireshark can't decode the payload. It is encrypted. That's what SSL is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a port that's not normally used for SSL/TLS, you will have to tell Wireshark to decode it as SSL/TLS explicitly.

Right click on a packet and choose *Decode As...* -> *Transport* -> *SSL*.

Comment: Doesn't buy you much. The payload is still encrypted. OP's expectations are misplaced.

Comment: @EJP ah, I'm not sure, I understood the question as "decoding" to be able to see the structure of the TLS messages. Decryption is another matter of course.

Comment: Wireshark doesn't give me the structure of the TLS message either.

Comment: @EJP I'm not sure what could be happening. It has always worked for me. If I run a server on a port where it doesn't think SSL is used (say 8443 or something else). Doing this on the TCP payload makes it appear as SSLv3/TLS (in the protocol column) and shows the Client Hello, Server Hello... (not the encrypted content of course).

Comment: @EJP Of course i cannot see the payload (o.O)@Bruno thank you it works! I believed that the decoding chosen by wireshark is based on some packet fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the private key, you can see the payload, just go tools->preference->ssl->edit and insert your key here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I resolved that a year ago. :D

Comment: And, anyway, it does not work if the TLS session uses Perfect Forward Secrecy (which it should).