# Why does my server always respond "No certificates"?

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl, protocols

I'm trying to use an SSL client/server example from: http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html to create a secure connection using SSLv3, without success.

I changed the client to try to load certificates in the client-side, added the `LoadCertificates` function that exists on server example.
I've created my certificates following [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL).

My problem is that, when I connect to server, the client side can see the information about certificate of server, but the server never loads information about certificate of client.

Here is my client code:

```
//SSL-Client.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define FAIL    -1

    //Added the LoadCertificates how in the server-side makes.    
void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
 /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
}

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port)
{   int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
    {
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = SSLv3_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
        printf("No certificates.\n");
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;
    char *hostname, *portnum;
    char CertFile[] = "/home/myCA/cacert.pem";
    char KeyFile[] = "/home/myCA/private/cakey.pem";

    SSL_library_init();
 hostname=strings[1];
 portnum=strings[2];

    ctx = InitCTX();
    LoadCertificates(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile);
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {   char *msg = "Hello???";

        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certs */
        SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));   /* encrypt & send message */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        SSL_free(ssl);        /* release connection state */
    }
    close(server);         /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */
    return 0;
}
```

And the server:

```
//SSL-Server.c
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

#define FAIL    -1

int OpenListener(int port)
{   int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        perror("can't bind port");
        abort();
    }
    if ( listen(sd, 10) != 0 )
    {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
    method = SSLv3_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
 /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* Get certificates (if available) */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);
        X509_free(cert);
    }
    else
        printf("No certificates.\n");
}

void Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{   char buf[1024];
    char reply[1024];
    int sd, bytes;
    const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

    if ( SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL )     /* do SSL-protocol accept */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {
        ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certificates */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
        if ( bytes > 0 )
        {
            buf[bytes] = 0;
            printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
            sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);   /* construct reply */
            SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply)); /* send reply */
        }
        else
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
    SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
    close(sd);          /* close connection */
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    char *portnum;

    char CertFile[] = "/home/myCA/cacert.pem";
    char KeyFile[] = "/home/myCA/private/cakey.pem";

    SSL_library_init();

    portnum = strings[1];
    ctx = InitServerCTX();        /* initialize SSL */
    LoadCertificates(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile); /* load certs */
    server = OpenListener(atoi(portnum));    /* create server socket */
    while (1)
    {   struct sockaddr_in addr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
        SSL *ssl;

        int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);  /* accept connection as usual */
        printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);              /* get new SSL state with context */
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);      /* set connection socket to SSL state */
        Servlet(ssl);         /* service connection */
    }
    close(server);          /* close server socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);         /* release context */
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have now changed `LoadCertificates` on the server as follows.

```
void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
    //New lines
    if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile) != 1)
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

    if (SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx) != 1)
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    //End new lines

    /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }

    //New lines
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
    //End new lines
}
```

After these change in `LoadCertificates`, when I start the server and make a connection from the client, it can see the information about certificate of server, and the server now loads information about certificate of client, but the protocol, as seen by Wireshar, does not change.

Indeed, following the changes suggested in the accepted answer, both the server side and the client side can see the certificates, but looking at the connection from Wireshark shows the protocol SSLv3(SSLv23, SSLv2, SSLv1) is not working. I don't understand what the problem is. Wireshark just shows protocol TCP or IPA, and for IPA packets, the info is always RSL Malformed Packet.

Comment: The question, as you've now edited it, sounds like a completely different question (or the two combined). It would be better to ask a different question in this case. You probably don't need to, though, since it sounds like the same problem as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10532296/372643).

Comment: Again, please don't re-edit by changing the initial text. If you have additions to make to the question, put them at the end. Following your recent changes (10 minutes ago), the answer now has nothing to do with the question. (As I was saying in my previous comment, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10532296/372643).)

Comment: I changed the question because I found a new problem. The first problem was the server-side not loaded the client certificate, and after of solves it I tested the protocol and it is not working like a communication TLS/SSL. If you use the socket example client and server using SSL on JAVA, the wireshark shows the protocol/info SSLv3/SSLv23 for example, and the example that I'm trying to do using C/C++ don't have the same behavior. The question have a lot of problems and I want solve all.

Comment: Ask a new question then!

Comment: Anyway, for your second problem, which port are you using?

Comment: So, once more, the solution to your problem is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10532296/372643): Wireshark doesn't guess that it's SSL/TLS when it's not on a port that normally uses SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_peer_certificate.html

> Due to the protocol definition, a TLS/SSL server will always send a
>   certificate, if present. A client will only send a certificate when
>   explicitly requested to do so by the server (see
>   SSL_CTX_set_verify(3)).

Server should call something like:

```
SSL_CTX_set_verify(SSL_get_SSL_CTX(ssl), SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
```

before:

```
if ( SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL )
```

Comment: Thank you.. because in your answer I found the book "Network Security with OpenSSL", the example server2.c.

Comment: For [reference](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4346#section-7.4.6): "*Client certificate. This is the first message the client can send after receiving a server hello done message.  This message is only sent if the server requests a certificate.*"