# Socket programming, what is FD and SD

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl

I am programming an SSL socket and many times I have seen something (variable name, function...) with FD or SD in its name. For example, OpenSSL provides the function:

```
int fd = SSL_get_fd(...);
```

In many tutorials ([here](http://languageshelp.blogspot.cz/2008/01/ssl-openssl-with-visual-c.html?m=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705815/client-and-server-communication-using-ssl-c-c-ssl-protocol-dont-works) and [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=22078)), this is used:

```
int sd = socket(...);
```

Can anyone explain, what does FD and SD stand for?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[SSL_get_fd](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_fd.html):

> SSL_get_fd() returns the **file descriptor**

[File Descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor):

> In Unix and related computers operating systems, a file descriptor (FD, less frequently fildes) is an abstract indicator used to access a file or other input/output resource, such as a pipe or network connection. File descriptors are part of the POSIX application programming interface. A file descriptor is a non-negative integer, represented in C programming language as the type int.

`wfd`, `rfd` will stand for write-FD and read-FD. `sd` is not a standard moniker, but it will likely stand for 'socket file descriptor', ie. a FD that corresponds to a socket. From the same `SSL_get_fd` page:

> fd will typically be the socket file descriptor of a network connection

Answer (score 5):

"fd" is generally an abbreviation of *File Descriptor*. On POSIX systems like Linux, OSX and the BSD variants a file descriptor is used not only for *files*, but for sockets, device communication and other things as well