# Client and Server communication using ssl c/c++ -Unable to use Certificates

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying use an SSL client/server example from:[Client and Server communication using ssl c/c++ - SSL protocol don't works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705815/client-and-server-communication-using-ssl-c-c-ssl-protocol-dont-works) to create a secure connection using TLSV1 --

I Want to know how to create certificates for this code so that there will communication between client & server.

It need server certificate, server key & client cacertificate and cakey 
 i  try to create it with the help of this link:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL
but it client unable to get connected to server shows unable to verify

Comment: This might be a place to start looking:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl

Comment: It would be good if you can post your code and the output (error codes, error strings etc)